# Using a TP LINK outdoor CPE as WLAN in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

i have a Tp-Link outdoor CPE (TL-WA5210G) and im using kali linux.

My question is... Can you turn this kind of outdoor CPE into a wlan in kali? The antenna is located on the roof an it is connected via Ethernet port. Is there any way to use it as a wifi port to crack a another wifi signal? or am i completely wasting my time?

Thanks

Comment: You are completely wasting your time. If you need to ask these questions, they belong on superuser.com and you should not be using Kali.

Answer (score 0):

The CPE is not just an antenna; it's a standalone device with its own OS. It cannot be made to show up as a `wlan0` device on a different system.

However, depending on the firmware, you *might* be able to install software directly into the CPE itself, or even OpenWRT the whole thing. I don't know if this is possible with TP-Link devices, but I've done so in the past with another manufacturer's 802.11b/g era CPEs.

For example, if it has `tcpdump` installed, it *can* capture the received Wi-Fi packets and send them to your computer over SSH for analysis (e.g. if you want to crack an old WEP network).

(There's nothing special about Kali; it's just a collection of software. If you can install the same software on any other Linux-based system, be it Ubuntu or OpenWRT, you can achieve the same results.)